# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in web map

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers-2, geoserver

I am having trouble getting a WFS layer working using Geoserver, OpenLayers and GeoExt.

I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.0.0.155/geoserver/wfs. Origin http://10.0.0.155:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Does anyone know how I get around this? I can't find anything in the examples for geoserver, openlayers or geoext.

I don't get any errors when using WMS on my maps.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: I use IIS for displaying maps and i have also this error what can i do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is this problem http://trac.openlayers.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

so you need to set up a proxy host as per those instructions.

Comment: Thanks for that. It has removed that error. Now I just have to find out why my data isn't showing on the map.

Comment: There are some really useful tools in firefox for debugging wms/wfs requests- if you don't already know about them. Try firebug and httpfox- that way you will see the actual request being sent to your server.

Comment: Thanks for the links those two - I shall try them out to see if they help.

Comment: I have added a proxy file but I am not sure what I need to put in it to make it work. My layer will work within QGIS so I am guessing it is a proxy problem or something like that.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am still facing the same problem and have no clue how to solve it

Answer (score -1):

Requests between domains is not allowed for XMLhttprequest stuff. 
Requesting JSONP as outputformat might also by a solution to. this not in the official OGC-spec, but  Geoserver supports this. But I don't know if openlayers supports jsonp. (there  is a plugin for leaflet that does ) 
See: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

Comment: Your Answer doesn't solve the issue. It can only be solved with a proxy file as given in the accepted answer.