# Drupal-Geoserver WFS error

Tags: geoserver, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in web map.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/access-control-allow-origin-error-in-web-map)

I am using Drupal and geoserver for my project. 
Drupal is running on localhost:80 and geoserver on localhost:8080. I want to send data from drupal to geoserver, and get it back to drupal to display it on a map. When I send the data to geoserver through the GetCapabilities URL I am not able to see the points in Layer->preview and the GML file is empty.

When I view the error in firebug its giving:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs.
>   Origin http://localhost is not allowed
>   by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

can anyone tell me what this means and how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: 16 questions so far and not a single one accepted yet!  (If you're not sure what this means, please read the FAQ.)